# Content under footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm having trouble dividing a page into `header`, `content` and `footer`.
I followed one of the topics here on stackoverflow. However, when I try adding anything to the content part all of my content appears below the `footer` element. So far, this is my code.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong and what is the reason behind it?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        //Removed
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="main-wrapper">
            <header>
                <?php 
                require('header.php');
                ?>
            </header>
            <section class="page-content">
                yeah
            </section>
           <footer>
                <?php 
                include('footer.php');
                ?>
           </footer>
       </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS

```
    body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }

    .main-wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    }

    article {
    background-color: white;
    }

    footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    height: 55px;
    }
    .page-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

    .nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;   
    }
```

The page-content appears below footer, even when I set it's position to absolute. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Try removing `height: 100%;` from page-content? It may be trying to fill the entire page-wrapper space.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

between your section and footer tag and see if that helps

Comment: Hi, just fund out that there's something wrong with my header. I add it using php. However when I delete the php code and just type any text then it works. I guess I will need to fix that. There should be nothing wrong with it though. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hey there, glad to hear you figured out the header issue. As for the PHP, have you double checked the php code you are pulling in? Maybe there is a tag that isn't closed or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-content {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:0 0 55px; /* make space for footer */
}
```